# How to change element positions in layout with Zurb Foundation

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm creating the layout for a web using Zurb Foundation and I've got a problem when re-sizing the browser.

This is my layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                Company image
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns">
                content1
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content2
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                content4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                Login
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When for tablet/phones etc the page shows just one column, it shows the divs in this order:

1. Company Imange
2. Content1
3. Content2
4. Content3
5. Content4
6. Login
7. ...

I want the login just below the Company Image, like this:

1. Company Image
2. Login
3. Content1
4. Content2
5. ....

How can I get this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your layout by adding row and put into that row only company image and login in two columns. After that paste your previous code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        Company image
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        Login
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="eight columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns">
                content1
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content2
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                content4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pepek. But with your solution, CompanyImage and Login will have the same height, something in the design I have to follow doesn't happen, that's why I created the two different columns.

Comment: When you are using show-for-small and hide-for-small it means that these parts are only hidden but they are existing both on the page. So in your case content1, content2 etc. are doubled - so data transfer is larger and filesize also. In my opinion it's better to use mobile grid with the standard grid.

Answer (score 0):

So in this case use [Mobile Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php#mobileEx) link to manage mobile layout. Make modification by this way (i set background color to make this example more clear).

Otherwise you can use "show-for-small" and "hide-for-small" styles and set up two different views (for mobile with fixed size but content will be redundant.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns " style="background-color:red">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        Company image
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns" style="background-color:blue">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="mobile-one"></div>
                    <div class="twelve columns mobile-three" style="background-color:gray">
                        Login
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns" style="background-color:red">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns">
                content1
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content2
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                content3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                content4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns" style="background-color:blue">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it with this, I saw your answer later and I think it's the same:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                Company Image
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="row hide-for-small">
            <div class="four columns">
                Content1
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                Content2
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                Content3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row hide-for-small">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                Content4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="row pull-four">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                @Html.Partial("_Login")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row show-for-small">
            <div class="four columns">
                Content1
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                Content2
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                Content3
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row show-for-small">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                Content4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Probably not the most elegant solution but it works very well!

What do you mean with your last sentence?